process json response as a stream
I have an http response with a body that is a ByteReadChannel. I know that the content is an array of JSON objects. I need to filter that response body by properties of the JSON object. As the array can potentially contain at least thousands of objects I would like to avoid reading the whole content into memory, apply my filters and send the result to the client.
How can I convert the ByteReadChannel to, let's say, a Flow<MyJsonObject> and filter on the flow? Flow is just an example, perhaps there are better classes to use...
PS: I use Ktor.

I don't think ktor supports this out of the box, but something that might fit your use case could be chaining https://api.ktor.io/ktor-io/io.ktor.utils.io.jvm.javaio/to-input-stream.html into https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.serialization/kotlinx-serialization-json/kotlinx.serialization.json/decode-to-sequence.html or jackson equivalent.
Note that these are both JVM-only, you might need to write your own stream parser logic if targeting other platforms. Also it will convert the whole thing into a blocking API (the result being a Sequence), which might not be wanted.

something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75441423/json-decoding-from-stream-in-kotlin ?

@somethingsomething: thanks for the hint. However, I was wrong in the first place, it is in fact exactly one Json Object that has an attribute which is the list to be filtered. To me this sounds different and kind of impossible to solve, am I right?

@Martin thats definitely possible, but you will need to write the logic yourself, I've never done this with ktor, and on the parsing side I only have experience doing this with jackson, using the streaming API: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api , you'll most likely need to wire this together with the ByteReadChannel and incrementally read the body until you get to the json key that you are interested in.
